# Check if key is pressed on background using win32api

Tags: python, winapi, keypress

I'm trying to make a simple Python script to capture image from my webcam on workstation unlock.
And I am making a "kill switch" that checks if key is pressed and if it does the program will not run.
My problem is that I need to check if key is pressed and I can't find a way to do that.
I have tried this:

```
 keyState = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(17)
```

But it does not work.

From the documentation:

> The return value is zero if a window in another thread or process
>   currently has the keyboard focus.

So it doesn't really help me.
I'm on Windows btw.

Comment: That is not exactly what the current documentation says.

Comment: "http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetAsyncKeyState_meth.html"
Can you explain please?

Comment: See the documentation on MSDN, it should work in most cases because most apps are not blocking hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `GetAsyncKeyState()` Also need to AND(&) 0x8000 to ensure the key is down.

> Return Value
>
> Type: SHORT
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

Note that the return value is bit-encoded (not a boolean). You should clear the the least significant bit like:

```
keyState = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(17)&0x8000.
```

And, there is a simple solution without window focus in python. You could get the it through [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/).

Command line:

```
> pip install pynput
```

Python code:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try: k = key.char # single-char keys
    except: k = key.name # other keys
    if key == *(which you want to set):#To Do.

lis = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
lis.start() # start to listen on a separate thread
lis.join() # no this if main thread is polling self.keys
```

Comment: I tried to use pynput but the problem is I want to check if a key is down even if you hold the key before the program has started. (hope you understand me.)
And also what do you mean by AND(&) 0x8000 can you please show the correct way to do it.

Comment: As @Anders says, it actually work within the scope of the whole system. So how dose `GetAsyncKeyState` not work. Is it return 0? or just the wrong bit value? If so, take the advice that I metioned in my answer, to clear the least significant bit. Or it was the code follow the key down event does not work?